# Large message lost for divert

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have following queue setup in cluster:

- server1 running on 61616
- server2 running on 61617

I start two consumer with two different available master server

```
java -jar AmqJmsConsume.jar -duration 5 -queue IT-InputQueue -stats -log
/tmp/artemis/4 -verify -commitdelay 300 -url 'tcp://localhost:61616'

java -jar AmqJmsConsume.jar -duration 5 -queue IT-InputQueue -stats -log
/tmp/artemis/4 -verify -commitdelay 300 -url 'tcp://localhost:61617'
```

and run producer to server1 as below

```
java -jar AmqJmsProducer.jar -topic RFTopic -stats -log /tmp/artemis/4 -id
-count 500 -n 500 -ttl 3600000 -url 'tcp://localhost:61616' -outliers 100
-outliersize 500k
```

both consumer gets few message but after below exception server1 clears
queue with almost 50% of messages but rest of messages are stuck with
internal.sf.cluster queue and not received by any consumer.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: no queueIDs defined
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionBridge.beforeForward(ClusterConnectionBridge.java:182) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.handle(BridgeImpl.java:653) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.handle(QueueImpl.java:3346) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.deliver(QueueImpl.java:2606) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.access$2300(QueueImpl.java:117) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl$DeliverRunner.run(QueueImpl.java:3613) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]

2019-07-29 10:21:38,503 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl] null: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.PriorityLinkedListImpl$PriorityLinkedListIterator.repeat(PriorityLinkedListImpl.java:172) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.deliver(QueueImpl.java:2627) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.access$2300(QueueImpl.java:117) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl$DeliverRunner.run(QueueImpl.java:3613) [artemis-server-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
```

**server1-master broker**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <thread-pool-max-size>400</thread-pool-max-size>
        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>${data.dir}/paging</paging-directory>

        <bindings-directory>${data.dir}/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>${data.dir}/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>${data.dir}/large-messages
        </large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

        <journal-min-files>20</journal-min-files>

        <journal-pool-files>20</journal-pool-files>

        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <journal-compact-min-files>30</journal-compact-min-files>

        <journal-buffer-timeout>23480000</journal-buffer-timeout>


        <!-- When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for 
            libaio. -->
        <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
        <!-- You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying 
            the <network-check-NIC> element. <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC> -->

        <!-- Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

        <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
        <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

        <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs it should 
            accept IPV6 Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this 
            is meant to validate if your network is valid. Using IPs that could eventually 
            disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose. You can use a list 
            of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue 
            running -->
        <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




        <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the 
            disk in ms -->
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the 
            connection in certain protocols that won't support flow control. -->
        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>LOG</critical-analyzer-policy>

        <transaction-timeout>1800000</transaction-timeout>
        <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This 
            is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory The 
            system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size. 
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your 
            needs. <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->
        <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
        </acceptors>


        <ha-policy>
            <shared-store>
                <master>
                    <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                </master>
            </shared-store>
        </ha-policy>

        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
                <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
                <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group" />
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

        <diverts>
            <divert name="RF-Transform">
                <routing-name>RFeeds-Transform</routing-name>
                <address>RFTopic</address>
                <forwarding-address>IT-InputQueue</forwarding-address>
                <exclusive>false</exclusive>
            </divert>
            <divert name="RF-Output">
                <routing-name>RFeeds-Output</routing-name>
                <address>RFTopic</address>
                <forwarding-address>T1-InputQueue</forwarding-address>
                <exclusive>false</exclusive>
            </divert>
        </diverts>
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
                <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be 
                auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <!--default for catch all -->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <redistribution-delay>10000</redistribution-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>

        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="IT-InputQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="IT-InputQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="T1-InputQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="T1-InputQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="RFTopic">
                <multicast />
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

**server-master broker**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <thread-pool-max-size>400</thread-pool-max-size>
        <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

        <paging-directory>${data.dir}/paging</paging-directory>

        <bindings-directory>${data.dir}/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>${data.dir}/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>${data.dir}/large-messages
        </large-messages-directory>

        <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

        <journal-min-files>20</journal-min-files>

        <journal-pool-files>20</journal-pool-files>

        <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

        <journal-compact-min-files>30</journal-compact-min-files>

        <journal-buffer-timeout>23480000</journal-buffer-timeout>


        <!-- When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for 
            libaio. -->
        <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
        <!-- You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying 
            the <network-check-NIC> element. <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC> -->

        <!-- Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

        <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
        <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

        <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs it should 
            accept IPV6 Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this 
            is meant to validate if your network is valid. Using IPs that could eventually 
            disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose. You can use a list 
            of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue 
            running -->
        <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

        <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
        <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




        <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the 
            disk in ms -->
        <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

        <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the 
            connection in certain protocols that won't support flow control. -->
        <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

        <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
        <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

        <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

        <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

        <critical-analyzer-policy>LOG</critical-analyzer-policy>

        <transaction-timeout>1800000</transaction-timeout>
        <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This 
            is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory The 
            system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size. 
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your 
            needs. <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->
        <connectors>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61617?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
        </acceptors>


        <ha-policy>
            <shared-store>
                <master>
                    <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                </master>
            </shared-store>
        </ha-policy>

        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
                <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
                <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
                <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group" />
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>



        <diverts>
            <divert name="RF-Transform">
                <routing-name>RFeeds-Transform</routing-name>
                <address>RFTopic</address>
                <forwarding-address>IT-InputQueue</forwarding-address>
                <exclusive>false</exclusive>
            </divert>
            <divert name="RF-Output">
                <routing-name>RFeeds-Output</routing-name>
                <address>RFTopic</address>
                <forwarding-address>T1-InputQueue</forwarding-address>
                <exclusive>false</exclusive>
            </divert>
        </diverts>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
                <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
                <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be 
                auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <!--default for catch all -->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
                <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
                <redistribution-delay>10000</redistribution-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
                <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>          
        </address-settings>

        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="IT-InputQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="IT-InputQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="T1-InputQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="T1-InputQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="RFTopic">
                <multicast />
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

**My Analysis:**
I have gone thru the code of artemis-server module and below are my findings.
The *org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl. route(message,context,direct,rejectDuplicates,bindingMove)* method clean the internal properties from the Message. Is there any reason to cleanup those properties. As I am getting above error because the properties "**_AMQ_ROUTE_TO$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.68d83229-be54-11e9-824e-f8b156cb82da**" is not present in message properties

We are cleaning up internal properties based on following condition.

```
package org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl
    public class CoreMessage extends RefCountMessage implements ICoreMessage {
       private static final Predicate<SimpleString> INTERNAL_PROPERTY_NAMES_PREDICATE =
          name -> (name.startsWith(Message.HDR_ROUTE_TO_IDS) && !name.equals(Message.HDR_ROUTE_TO_IDS)) ||
             (name.startsWith(Message.HDR_ROUTE_TO_ACK_IDS) && !name.equals(Message.HDR_ROUTE_TO_ACK_IDS));
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the latest release (i.e. 2.9.0)? Also, can you share the client code and broker configuration?

Comment: I have reproduce with release 2.9.0. Can you please download client code from github url: github.com/erik-wramner/JmsTools.git. Also I have added broker.xml for server1-master and server2-master in above description

Comment: Can you update the question so that the stack-trace is the one from 2.9.0 rather than 2.6.3?

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: I have updated my question with my analysis. Can you please look into it